# iphone - apns to open an application without pop-up

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is there a way to open an application without showing the pop-up notification or is this possible only through iOS Enterprise program with Mobile Device Management feature?

currently I have this which shows ok after a pop-up.
self.updateos = @"{\"aps\":{\"alert\":{\"action-loc-key\":\"\", \"body\":\"update please\"}},\"acme1\":\"updateos\",\"acme2\":42}";

I tried to find answer from here but couldn't...
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW10

I want users to go into my program right after I send a push notification.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off adding buttons to the push notification, or better yet in iOS 5, they can slide it in the lock screen. If a push notification pops up while they're in a different app, I think it would be kind of annoying for the user to be switched to your app, and possibly against the review guidelines as well.

Comment: I'm trying to make Mobile Device Management application which does functions like remote wipe, in case when user's phone is lost. There shouldn't be a prompt for this kind of service. Getting iOS Enterprise program is probably the answer. Thanks though.

Comment: Mac OS X Lion Server includes this feature in "Profile Manager". It's pretty cool, and you should check it out.